# Render a single react component in a html file (webpack)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a simple react component to a html page, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
// hello.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>
    )
  }
}

// index.html
<html>
<body>
</body>
<head>

    <!-- HTML code -->

    <!-- RENDER HERE -->

</head>
</html>
```

webpack and babel:

```
// index.js 
import Hello from './hello.js'
```

If i put this line at the end of Hello.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

I can render the component with:

```
// index.html
<div id="hello"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

However, There are times where I don't want to render the component, or render it after a certain time interval. If I remove the div i get an error:

```
Target container is not a DOM element
```

I guess I want to do something like this (Which doesn't work)

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<head>

    <!-- HTML code -->

    <!-- RENDER HERE -->
    <div id="hello"></div>

    <script src="bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
        },1000);

        // or 

        if (true) {
            ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, document.getElementById('hello'));
        } 
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
And question nr 2. How do I pass props to the component?

Comment: You should probably wrap your component with an other component implementing the logic about when you want to render or not the sub component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with this CodePen and do some experiments first to get comfortable with React.

## [React example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw/)

### There are times where I don't want to render the component, or render it after a certain time interval.

If you use React the right way, you would achieve this behavior by using `States` or `Props`. Each time a `State` or a `Prop` changes, all affected `Components` are re-rendered automatically.

### How do I pass props to the component?

This is as simple as this:

```
<MyComponent firstProp={true} secondProp={new Date()} />
```

And to access this inside `MyComponent`:

```
render() {

console.log( this.props.firstProp );

...

}
```

You should also check out [8 no-Flux strategies for React component communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/). This guide helped me a lot, when I first started with ReactJS.